# Get fs.stat when fs.watch detect a file unlink

Tags: node.js, fs

I can't get fs.stat when fs.watch detect an "unlink" event, I only get "undefined"

```
fs.watch("./someFolder", {recursive: true}, (event, path) => {
  fs.stat(path, (err, stats) => console.log(stats.ino));
})
```

There is a way to get at least the inode of the file unlink?

Answer (score 0):

**it returns 'undefined' as the file has been unlinked**.

'path' gives you only the filename. Use '**require('path').join(/dir/of/that/file,path)**' to get the fullpath.

You create a map **{fullpath (key) => inode (value)}**.
Add entries either on 'add' (create) event or periodically add the entries.

on the 'unlink' event, you can use the fullpath to fetch the inode value from the map.

P.S: Getting 'undefined' on 'unlink' with [chokidar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chokidar) module also.